# Import class and add to array dynamically

Tags: java

I am trying to make an IRC bot that can have commands added to it by users. For this, I have put all the existing commands in external files referred to using an interface. I have already figured out how to make the bot interpret the command to make the file for a new command and compile it, which works perfectly, except that I have to shut down the bot, open the source for it, add the new command to the bot's array of available commands, and then run it again.

What I would like it to do is after compiling the new command, automatically add it to the array of available commands. I have looked for a while and from what I found, I think I need to make a method that returns a class so that that can be added to the array, but I am not sure. If there is any code I need to post, feel free to ask. As it is though, I don't have any code on this specific operation.

Comment: These existing commands are in `.java` files? What have you tried? Have you looked at the (now build in) compiler and classloaders?

Comment: You obviously need some kind of plugin framework, OSGi for example, to swap behaviour at runtime.

Comment: For the compiler side of things, I already have it set up so that it takes user's message and makes a full, usable command from it. From that point though I have to shut down the bot and add the class to the array in the bot's code.

For the classloader side of things, I have absolutely no clue how to use one.

Comment: @Smutje Would that remove one of my other commands from being usable? And also, I would rather not have to add any sort of framework. I would like to do this using only built-in Java functions.

Comment: You may want to create a custom class loader that can load new classes on the fly after dropping the .class in a folder or something.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And how exactly would I do that? I already have the .class file in the location I want it when it is compiled by the bot.

Comment: What about searching *java create custom class loader* in your favorite SEO? :)